# Tags to include text before $params function

Tags: php

Maybe its me that has just gone blind, but

I have

```
<contact:cc>".$params["original"]["country"]."</contact:cc>
```

Thats gives example : "Norway"

I want to add a text that is always in front of norway or the contry

I tried following:

```
<contact:cc>".Sometext. $params["original"]["country"]."</contact:cc>
```

But it doesnt include the text, any ideas,what could be wrong.

Comment: You didn't put the text in quotes? Although that's a mistake, it *should* print the text anyway. Show us the real code.

Comment: @Jon: So long as there is no `define('Sometext', '')`, which I doubt :)

Comment: Its not define anything for "sometext" sometext should be plain text before the ".$params["original"]["country"]." that returns the Country where the client lives.

Answer (score 1):

```
"<contact:cc>Sometext" . $params["original"]["country"] . "</contact:cc>"
```

The extra text is still part of the string, so treat it as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

echo $sometext.$params["original"]["country"];

?>
```

should work.

if its inside of html like the example you gave above do this:

```
<contact:cc><? echo $sometext.$params["original"]["country"]; ?></contact:cc>
```

Comment: Its a php file, and "sometext" is not someting defined another place, this should only be plain text before the ".$params["original"]["country"]." that returns the clients country